# PHP : Corrupt ZIP when download large multiple files

Tags: php

I got an error when I download large multiple files like 5 videos

Here is the code :

HTML5 code :

```
<input type='checkbox' name='files[]' value="<?php echo $row['video_name']; ?>">
```

PHP code :

```
header('Content-type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zip_name.'"');readfile($zip_name);
unlink($zip_name);
```

Comment: What's the error?  How can we help you with an error when you didn't even say what the error is?  Also, be very sure that the file you're retrieving is in the path you expect it to be.  Don't let someone download whatever file they want.  Also, use `htmlspecialchars()` around any arbitrary data used in the context of HTML, or you risk generating invalid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what the error is, I'll take a stab in the dark:

```
ini_set("max_execution_time", 300);
```

My guess is your script is timing out.  Hard to say without more data tho.